# Is there a way to create a working set in PhpStorm like in Eclipse in order to group by projects?

Tags: php, phpstorm, working-set

Coming from the Eclipse world, I started using PhpStorm to develop in PHP. I would like to ask if there's a way to group by similar projects in order to see them like in the Eclipse's working set feature, with a view such as:

```
Projects
----------------------------------------
LibrariesProjects
    -------> APhpLibraryProject
    -------> AnotherPhpLibraryProject
    -------> YetAnotherPhpLibraryProject
ProjectsRelatedToOtherStuff
    -------> AProject
    -------> AnotherProject
    -------> Etc...
Etc..
```

I mean, in Eclipse I can e.g. create a **LibraryProjects** working set and add projects to it (like e.g. **APhpLibraryProject**, **AnotherPhpLibraryProject**), in order to not see a plenty list of different projects on the left side of the IDE...

Is it possible in PhpStorm?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: As fully independent projects (with own settings etc) in single frame -- nope -- only one project per frame/window. But if you need to add just files and be able to edit them -- yes -- use Additional Content Root (`Settings | Project | Directories`); if those projects/libraries are needed for reference purpose only (code completion) and not editing then use External Libraries (`Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP -> Include paths`).

Comment: What do you mean with `Additional Content Root`? I can't find it in `Settings | Project | Directories` in version 8.0.2. Do you mean the `Add Context Root` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note really: you cannot have them as fully independent projects (with own settings etc) in single frame at the moment -- only one project per frame/window.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15187 -- watch this ticker (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

But if you need to just **add files to the project and be able to edit them** (as part of the actual project -- they will participate in global search/replace; refactorings & deployment checked for errors etc) -- yes, just use **Additional Content Root** functionality (`Settings | Project | Directories --> Add Content Root` button).

If those projects/libraries are needed for **reference purpose only** (code completion) and not editing then use **External Libraries** (`Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP -> Include paths`).